# Pure Java Binding in ZK Listbox with itemRenderer

Tags: java, binding, listbox, zk

I will want to use Data binding in Java Class rather than

> @bind

With each **ListCell** in **Listbox**.
 I tried with this example

My ZUl File...

```
<zk>
  <window border="normal" title="hello" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.test.binding.TestRenderer')" >
     <button label="ClickMe" id="retrieve"
                        onClick="@command('onOK')">
                    </button>
    <div height="800px">
      <listbox model="@load(vm.model)" itemRenderer="@load(vm.itemRenderer)" vflex="true" multiple="true"/>
    </div>
  </window>
</zk>
```

My Java Class or ViewController.....

```
package com.test.binding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.AfterCompose;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Command;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ContextParam;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ContextType;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component;
import org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.AnnotateDataBinder;
import org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.Binding;
import org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.BindingListModelList;
import org.zkoss.zul.ListModel;
import org.zkoss.zul.ListModelList;
import org.zkoss.zul.Listcell;
import org.zkoss.zul.Listitem;
import org.zkoss.zul.ListitemRenderer;
import org.zkoss.zul.Textbox;


public class TestRenderer {

    ListModelList model = new ListModelList();
    private AnnotateDataBinder binder;

    @AfterCompose
    public void afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {
        binder = new AnnotateDataBinder(view);
     List persons = new ArrayList();    
     model.add(new Person("David", "Coverdale"));
     model.add(new Person("Doug", "Aldrich"));
     model.add(new Person("Reb", "Beach"));
     model.add(new Person("Michael", "Devin"));
     model.add(new Person("Brian", "Tichy"));


        binder.loadAll(); 


    }

    public void setModel(ListModelList model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public ListModel getModel() {

        return model;
    }

    // method for ZK 6
    public ListitemRenderer getItemRenderer() {
        ListitemRenderer _rowRenderer = null;
        if (_rowRenderer == null) {

            _rowRenderer = new ListitemRenderer() {
                public void render(final Listitem item,   Object object,
                        int index) throws Exception {
                    final Person dataBean = (Person) object;

                    binder.bindBean(item.getId() , dataBean);

                    Listcell cell = new Listcell();
                    Textbox name = new Textbox();
                    name.setValue(dataBean.getFirstName());
                    System.out.println(item.getId()+ "------------------>"+item.getId() + ".name");
                    //binder.addBinding(name, "value", item.getId()+i + ".name", null, null, "both", null, null, null, null);
                    //binder.addBinding(name, "value",item.getId() + ".name", new String[] {}, "none", "both", null);
                    cell.appendChild(name);
                    //cell.addAnnotation(cell, "bind", null);
                    cell.setParent(item);

                }
            };
            binder.saveAll();
            binder.loadAll();
        }
        return _rowRenderer;
    }
    @Command
    public void onOK() {
        binder.saveAll(); //load Inputfields from Form, Constraints will be performed

        binder.loadAll(); 
       Collection<Binding> test =  binder.getAllBindings();
        System.out.println(model);
      }
    public class Person {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        public Person(String fn, String ln) {
            setFirstName(fn);
            setLastName(ln);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }
        public void setFirstName(String fn) {
            firstName = fn;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
        public void setLastName(String ln) {
            lastName = ln;
        }

    }

    @Command
     public void clickMe(){
        BindingListModelList blml =  (BindingListModelList) getModel();

        for (Object object : blml) {
          System.out.println(Integer.parseInt((String) object));
        }
    }
}
```

Can any one give me the Demo Example How Binding should work with

> getItemRendered()

In **Listbox**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, using ListitemRenderer with MVVM is not so bad, sometimes it can be the 'bridge' between zul page and ViewModel, and it can be considered as a part of component (since once you assign a model, listbox will use default renderer to render item if you do not assign a template or a custom renderer) (see [List Model](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVC/Model/List_Model)). If there is nothing bad that assign only model and render items by default renderer, there is nothing bad assign both model and custom renderer to render items.

Let's define what the 'good' is at first:
-- The zul file do not need to know how ViewModel works, just ask for data and trigger command as needed.
-- The ViewModel do not need to know anything in zul page, just provide data and process some predefined event.

Now thinking about a simple scenario like the one described in the official document:
[Performing Actions on Events](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Essentials/Displaying%20information%20using%20the%20Listbox%20and%20MVVM/Performing%20Actions%20on%20Events)

see this line

```
onClick="@command('deleteOrder', cartItem=cartItem)"
```

and this line

```
public void deleteOrder(@BindingParam("cartItem") CartItem cartItem)
```

In this case, the zul page need to know bring the param to deleteOrder command while event triggered, and even have to know the param should assign the variable named cartItem in ViewModel. On the other hand, the ViewModel need to retrieve the param passed from zul page.

This is obviously not the 'good' situation.

With the ListitemRenderer, let's say ShoppingcartOrderlistItemRenderer, we can simply post an event to Listbox (e.g., onDeleteOrder) with the required data, then make it becomes

```
<listbox onDeleteOrder="@command('deleteOrder')" ...
```

and

```
public void deleteOrder(@ContextParam(ContextType.TRIGGER_EVENT) DeleteOrderEvent event) {
    getShoppingCart().remove(event.getProductId());
}
```

Rely on an event instead of rely on a param defined in zul page, I think this is more robust.

Finally, still have to say, just personal opinion.

Comment: Hi Benbai ,I have restriction to use the itemrendered() due to reordering and Sorting

Comment: In the other hand, I don not think this is a good way either, it would be better if MVVM has some mechanism to do the similar work.

Comment: But if you are using reordering and saving that order into database its hard to use the listbox purely in zul because you have fix listcell inside zul and it will not serve the requirement.Can you please provide some example where you used databinding with getitemrendered it will very helpful

Comment: I've done it yesterday http://ben-bai.blogspot.tw/2012/12/zk-listbox-inplace-editing-with.html

Comment: <I will try to look and let u know if i will get any issue

Comment: Hi BebBai is this possible With MVVM? http://zkfiddle.org/sample/4k499d/1-Reorder-Columns-in-Listbox#source-2 I will want to apply this thing With MVVM Architecture But in my case header will come from DualListbox The User will select the header with any order then i have to show data to user in Listbox.Is this Possible

Comment: answered at the related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040772/zk-reordering-with-listbox-without-drag-and-drop-event

Comment: How can i connected with you in any chat,I searched in your blog but no contact infomration

Comment: Because I do not have any personal chat software account (or say I do not chat for a long time)

Comment: Its ok can i get ur mail id so that i can define my problem in detail so that u can guide me

Comment: I think blog/stackoverflow are enough, actually I seldom check mail from gmail, much more view blog/SF directly.

Comment: That's right, and I've replied your comment at another thread.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to mix different paradigms. You want to use databinding especially MVVM style but also introduce your custom renderer in the process. Even if this works I think it is a VERY bad practice. Either go pure MVVM databinding where you separate your view from model and only define binding in your view or go with pure MVC and use your own renderer to render your model data anyway you want.

The whole point of databinding is to let binder take care of rendering/updating component state based on databinding annotations.

Talking specifically about your sample code here you are using `org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer` which will init a binder instance automatically and after that you are also explicitly instantiating a separate `AnnotateDataBinder` in `@AfterCompose` so there will be conflict between these two.

My suggestion would be to go with pure MVVM databinding by introdcing `<template>` in your view and let MVVM binder to render this template using `@Bind` or `@Load` annotations OR go with pure Java style MVVM databinding as described in this "[MVVM in Java](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2012/August/MVVM_In_Java)" article

Comment: Thanks but i can not use @bind because in my list i am using Soring and reordering so i can not fix cell in ZUl FIle.Any other suggestion

Answer (score 0):

@subodh

You can also try add EventListener in ListitemRenderer and pass some custom event with required data to listbox then bind that custom event to ViewModel, please refer to 
[the sample project at github](https://github.com/benbai123/ZK_Practice/tree/master/Pattern/MVVM/RendererWithMVVM) and [the demo online](http://screencast.com/t/XZNxVOzbs)

Edit:

A related post at my blog: [ZK Listbox: Event Processing with Renderer and MVVM](http://ben-bai.blogspot.tw/2012/12/zk-listbox-event-processing-with.html)

Comment: Thanks Benbai, I was also expecting your answer in ZK forum .But may be you was busy I will explain you my problem in details