# ZK Reordering With Listbox Without Drag And Drop Event

Tags: zk

As i am trying [This](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/4k499d/1-Reorder-Columns-in-Listbox#source-2) example well define by **Nabil Abdel-Hafeez**

It is working fine with some small issue which i already mentioned in tracker as issue. But i will want to Open a DualBox modal window in which  one listbox contain all header name and other listbox  will contain which  header we will want to show for a listbox(I did this with getitemrendered ).I will want to use same ZUL Code without **getitemrendered** method.But user can hide the header which he/she do not want to see for a listbox. Anyone did this type of things?
[Here](http://zk.datalite.cz/examples?p_p_id=ZKDLDemo_WAR_ZKDLDemo11&demoType=ZUL_ONLY)

The green image with + Sign showing same thing which i will want to implement.

As I was trying the  **Nabil Abdel-Hafeez** but my issue is that i will provide duallistbox where user can select which header he/she will want to see in listbox, user can select header by clicking on button ,user can add one header or all header from duallistbox and when user click on the Reorder button of duallistbox then it will reorder .In Nabil demo he is doing something like this..

```
for (Listitem item : lHead.getListbox().getItems()) {
  item.insertBefore(item.getChildren().get(from), item.getChildren().get(to));
}
```

But if user selecting multiple how we will track which will come first which second and so on..

Comment: Can any one have any demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try combine MVVM with forEach so you can construct String array to display, this works since 6.0.2

e.g.,

**zul**

```
<zk>
    <div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('test.TestVM')">
        <listbox model="@load(vm.model)">
            <listhead>
                <listheader forEach="${vm.headers}" label="${each}" />
            </listhead>
            <template name="model" var="cells">
                <listitem>
                    <listcell forEach="${cells}" label="${each}" />
                </listitem>
            </template>
        </listbox>
        <button label="original seq" onClick="@command('originalSeq')" />
        <button label="reverse" onClick="@command('reverse')" />
    </div>
</zk>
```

**VM**

```
package test;

import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Command;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.NotifyChange;

import org.zkoss.zul.ListModel;
import org.zkoss.zul.ListModelList;

import java.util.*;

public class TestVM {
    private int[] _original = {1, 2, 3};
    private int[] _reverse = {3, 2, 1};
    private int[] _seq = _original;
    private List _rawData;

    public String[] getHeaders () {
        String[] headers = new String[_seq.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _seq.length; i++) {
            int idx = _seq[i];
            headers[i] = (idx == 1? "First Name" :
                            idx == 2? "Last Name" :
                            idx == 3? "Age" : "");
        }
        return headers;
    }
    public ListModel getModel () {
        if (_rawData == null) {
            getRawData();
        }
        List modelData = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < _rawData.size(); i++) {
            Person data = (Person)_rawData.get(i);
            String[] cells = new String[_seq.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < _seq.length; j++) {
                cells[j] = data.getValue(_seq[j]);
            }
            modelData.add(cells);
        }
        return new ListModelList(modelData);
    }
    public void getRawData () {
        _rawData = new ArrayList();
        _rawData.add(new Person("First Name 01", "Last Name 01", 21));
        _rawData.add(new Person("First Name 02", "Last Name 02", 22));
        _rawData.add(new Person("First Name 03", "Last Name 03", 23));
    }
    @Command
    @NotifyChange("model")
    public void originalSeq () {
        _seq = _original;
    }
    @Command
    @NotifyChange("model")
    public void reverse () {
        _seq = _reverse;
    }
    class Person {
        private String _firstName;
        private String _lastName;
        private int _age;

        public Person (String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
            _firstName = firstName;
            _lastName = lastName;
            _age = age;
        }

        public String getFirstName () {
            return _firstName;
        }
        public String getLastName () {
            return _lastName;
        }
        public int getAge () {
            return _age;
        }
        public String getValue (int i) {
            return i == 1? getFirstName() :
                    i == 2? getLastName() :
                    i == 3? getAge() + "" : "";
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding forEach, please refer to [ZK Iterative Evaluation](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Composing/ZUML/Iterative_Evaluation)

### **Edit**

Fully binded sample at ZK fiddle

[Listbox Reorder Cells](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/a4ruol/5-Listbox-Reorder-Cells)

Comment: First Question strike in my mind ,let us suppose i have different component in different cell like one cell contain textbox,one datebox,one radiobox etc. then in that case how reordering  will work with MVVM Architect will it possible to do reordering?

Comment: You can use the "if" statement (refer to http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML%20Reference/ZUML/Attributes/if), I've created a sample at zkfiddle http://zkfiddle.org/sample/a4ruol/1-Listbox-Reorder-Cells

Comment: So you mean if we have different component in different cell then we can add   all component in single cell and check which component we have to display in which cell.And binding will work easily? As in my case i have listbox with different component in each cell as i already told in my last comment ,Now i have to add reordering and binding as well in ZUl page so both can be done within ZUL without getitemrendered() as i did previously. Or may be i am not able to explain my problem in details

Comment: One more thing in my reordering user can hide some header so cell data also hide for that header and header name will come from DB.Also here how you will get change value of any cell?

Comment: The sample above is not binding value via mvvm but use EL, to bind value directly, these articles may helps: http://www.zkoss.org/forum/listComment/20167-Extending-Grid-with-programmatically-configured-columns-position , http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer's%20Reference/MVVM/Data%20Binding/EL%20Expression

Comment: Thanks but i took inspiration from this forum post and created listbox with reordering but from getitemrendered() as i already told you but in that case everyone have to write lots of line code. Also binding is hard with this apporach so i was trying to get listbox reordering with everything in ZUL page means Listheader,Listitem and in listcell i will use @bind so we have to write less code ,will reoredering approach will work with if i will create listbox in ZUL page

Comment: Please refer to the updated sample for a "mixed" version, use forEach and if statement via EL and bind values via MVVM http://zkfiddle.org/sample/a4ruol/2-Listbox-Reorder-Cells

Comment: I am getting   
Property 'age' not writable on type ja4ruol$v2.Person  in each field you bind if i am changing anything and clicking outside

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22717/discussion-between-subodh-and-benbai123)

Comment: As binding throw exception the header not moving according t cell :(

Comment: I made the changes in your example